# root file system stays read-only

Tags: mount, initramfs, readonly, root-filesystem

I am currently trying to start working with an embedded linux device (arm). When I am trying to install packages it fails saying that some `/usr/...` path points to a read-only filesystem. 
By looking at `/proc/mounts` I found out that `/dev/root` is indeed mounted at `/` with the `ro` flag. 
I found out that doing `mount -o remount,rw /` did remount it in a writable fashion. But I would like to make this permanent. 
The things I tried (unsuccessfully):

1. Edit the uBoot kernel parameters so that the initramfs parameters do not longer contain the `ro` flag but rather the `rw` one (I am not so confident about these initramfs things and this `/dev/root` scares me a bit as it does not show up in the normal file hierarchy)
2. As 1. did not work (after a reboot) I also tried to remove the `ro` from the `fstab` parameters (where the device shows up again, despite being used for initramfs)

The second try also did not make the root fs any more writable than it was at the beginning sadly. Is there something I am missing here (in the chain of mounting volumes after boot)? I would be very grateful for any kind of help

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes Linux mounts hard drives in a funny way. Just for reference: I have a Debian based OS which randomly mounts **/dev/sda/** as **/dev/sdb/** and vice versa. I haven't experienced any of those problems and my **fstab** file includes the **ro** (read only) parameter.

I believe that the following part in **fstab** mounts the filesystem in **ro** mode if and only if errors have been encountered while attempting to boot in normal mode: 
**"/dev/mapper/sda3_crypt /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1"**
(I have LUKS encrypted partitions, so instead of **/dev/sda** i have **/dev/mapper/sda3_crypt**)

That was put in place to prevent potential damage to the filesystem if errors were detected while trying to mount it in normal mode.

Edit: You shouldn't alter your **fstab** in that way which removes protection.

Do you have mechanical Hard Disk Drive? If yes, try to run **fsck** to check and fix your filesystem: **fsck -fy /dev/sd(X)(Y)** where X, Y are your hard disk and boot partition with which you have troubles.

To find your drive(s), do **fdisk -l | more** to list all your Hard Disk Drives and partitions one screen at a time.

I hope this works for you well.